# Turn off screen keyboard when using touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

Screen keyboard always show up every time I tap on a blank space or input field on the touch screen on my laptop. I've already turned off screen keyboard in settings -> accessibility -> screen keyboard, but the screen keyboard still keeps showing up. I have to tap on the `ˇ` button to close the screen keyboard every time. Is there any way to turn off the screen keyboard for good?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use the Gnome extension **Block Caribou**, it's always worked for me (currently on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and Gnome 42.5).

See here:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/

or here:

https://github.com/keringar/cariboublocker